# Android M permission grant callback

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am testing the permission system on the Android M Dev Preview. I have a question about the callback function. The Activity class has a new API:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, 
               String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) { }
```

I want to ask why are permissions and grantResults arguments defined as arrays ? I know that multiple permissions can be asked at the same time using `requestPermissions()`, but if a request code is used for a permission set of request, wouldn't it suffice to just have an integer grantResults (not sure about permissions argument) ?

Comment: In addition to what the answer states, I suggest using this library to facilitate the process https://github.com/kayvannj/PermissionUtil

Comment: similar to the library mentioned above, i found a helper library at https://github.com/anthonycr/Grant, thanks to both devs! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the user can independently grant or deny any permissions that you request.

For example, suppose that I have:

```
  private static final String[] PERMS_ALL={
    CAMERA,
    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  };
```

and I call:

```
requestPermissions(PERMS_ALL, RESULT_PERMS_ALL);
```

`CAMERA` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are in separate permission groups. The user will be prompted, *per group*, to grant or deny the permission. They supply results per permission, because we request permissions (instead of groups). But the user could:

- grant both
- deny both
- grant `CAMERA` but not `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- grant `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but not `CAMERA`

Hence, they give us the full roster of results.

Personally, I don't use those results and call `checkSelfPermission()`, just in case of some bizarre race condition where I don't get called with `onRequestPermissionResult()` for a bit and the user changes their mind via Settings first.